# Interpreting a (function of) probability distribution as a random variable?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, statistics, random-variables, entropy

Consider, for example, [Wikipedia's definition of the entropy of of a discrete random variable $X$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Definition):

> $$H(X) = \mathbb{E}[I(X)] = \mathbb{E}[-ln(P(X))]$$ Here $\mathbb{E}$
>   is the expected value operator, and $I$ is the information content of
>   $X$. $I(X)$ is itself a random variable.

Since $I(X)$ is a function of $P(X)$, the PMF $P(X)$ itself is considered to be a random variable that takes on the value $P(x)$ in the event $X=x$. Is my interpretation correct?

A bit of a background: I see this kind of thing a lot in statistics problems dealing with KL divergence (e.g. in EM or variational inference where we often deal with $\mathbb{E}_{q(z)}[logp(z|\theta)]$), and I've always treated the expected value operator like a "macro" where I substitute $\mathbb{E}_{q(z)}[\cdot]$ with $\sum_z \cdot q(z)$ or $\int \cdot q(z) dz$ provided that the argument is some function of some random variable. I'm not sure if this treatment is correct, considering the formal definition of the "expected value operator".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the PMF/PDF is a function $P(\cdot)$ that takes in some $x$ and gives you a real umber. In these quantities that you mention, we plug in the random variable itself as the argument, so $P(X)$ is random.

Yes your interpretation of expectation is fine. **Note that these quantities are just special cases of functions of random variables.** For a random variable $X$ I am sure you understand what $f(X)$ and $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]$ denote. Here we are just thinking of special cases of $f$, such as a PMF/PDF like $P(\cdot)$ or a log likelihood $\log p(\cdot \mid \theta)$